# Can you query, translate, and open .dwg files from web.autocad.com's Web & Mobile directories?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

**Background:** I have a simple integration (Client App) using the Forge API that can: create a bucket, upload a .dwg file to the object storage service, translate the file (and get translation status), query the files in a bucket, and open any of the files in the bucket in the Viewer.  I'm now researching the possibility to pull files that are made/modified from the AutoCAD Web & Mobile App (https://web.autocad.com/) (aka the Web App) via the forge API.  Is this possible?

**Usecase:** We want some personnel to be able to modify the underlying files, whereas others just need to view it from an existing application integrated through forge. The idea would be the engineers would modify the file in the Web App, and then from the Client App using the forge API, I want to query to see if the base file has been updated since the last time it was translated for the viewer.  If newer, re-translate the file and view it.  If not, just view it.

**Attempts:** I assumed the files would be in a project in a hub in the [/project/v1/hubs/](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/field-guide/) in the data management API of Forge, but I'm getting a response of "You don't have permission to access this API".  I am in the trial version of forge, so that may be the issue.  And the Web App is currently "free for everyone for an extended period."  Is it possible that I just need to purchase one of the subscriptions to be able to access the files I have on the web app?  Or am I looking in the entirely wrong place?

**So, concisely, here are the questions:**

1. Are files that are saved on https://web.autocad.com/ accessible via the Forge API?  How, if yes?
2. If yes to #1, do these files need to be converted using the Forge API to be render-able in the Viewer?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it's a pretty cool idea and workflow, but unfortunately, AFAIK, we don't have direct access to file on https://web.autocad.com/ by Forge API currently, only data within Autodesk SAAS applications include BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team (formerly known as A360 Team), BIM 360 Docs, A360 Personal could be accessed directly, refer https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/overview/, But some ideas:

I am not expert on https://web.autocad.com, but I know it provides the connection to cloud storage including Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, and Microsoft OneDrive, depends on which cloud storage you are using, you should pick the corresponding API to access the file, and maybe check if the file is changed, all of that is nothing to do with Forge, but the cloud storage.

If you can check the file version with the API from cloud storage provider, then you should be able to exchange the file between the cloud storage and Autodesk OSS(check sample https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage ), you can use the Forge to translate and view files on Autodesk OSS.